# Notify activity, about changes in another activity. Is this possible?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have **Activity A** and **Activity B**. **Activity B** has some `checkbox`. I want to tell **Activity A**, as soon as user interacts with that **checkbox**. Is this possible to notify, and if yes. How?

Comment: Generally speaking, there's no guarantee that any other activity on the system is still "alive" while a one activity is active. You should generally have both activities referring to a common data sources, such as a `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Sounds as if your idea of the purpose of Activity objects is wrong. StackOverflow is about coding, but if you don't get flagged, you may want to describe what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*as soon as the user interacts with that check box*" is not applicable here. Android only loads one activity at a time. But I guess you want to transfer data between your activities so changes in B can trigger changes in A.

[This link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) will bring you to Android Developers. Scroll down to **build an Intent** and you'll learn all you need to know.